# I tried running a pod with nginx image. I am inside my VM, but the pod is not getting created

Tags: kubernetes, nodes

I have installed OracleVM, and created an Ubuntu machine. I have not tried any major cluster or tried deploying anything, I have started reading about Kubernetes and as an example just tried creating a simple pod. But I am getting host error, can anyone tell me where am I going wrong?

I have tried the simple `kubectl run` command
[The snip of my issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kg5UT.png)

Comment: Please do not post error messages as images. [Check here why.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557)

Comment: Could be an issue with you kube config. Can you share it - of course WITHOUT certificat/key data.

Comment: okay, I'll post the errors from next time

Answer (score 0):

You need to disable swap on the system for kubelet to work. You can disable swap with sudo `swapoff -a` and restart kubelet service `sudo systemctl restart kubelet`